Excel STOCKHISTORY function auto corrects to wrong ticker
I need stock prices for several stocks and funds. But some funds are causing me trouble for example “UniFonds” excel seems to auto correct it to “UniFonds -net-“ which is a different Stock with a different price.
=STOCKHISTORY("UniFonds";"01.11.2024";"05.11.2024")

this function returns the price of the fund UniFonds -net- not UniFonds
STOCKHISTORY example

Stock search

How can I force excel to use the name I put in without changing it. Or is there a way to use the unique ISIN number instead of the Name of the Fund?

When you write UniFonds first convert to Stocks Data Type --> Select the specific Stocks from the Data Type Panel. Next use this cell reference in STOCKHISTORY() function to get the desired output!

This works,
but when I change something and klick on that cell it changes the content to the wrong stock without warning.
And my main problem is when I use Stockhistory in vba script, sometimes I get an error 400 when calling Stockhistory and it does not go away without redoing/refreshing the stock data cells.
Because of that I’m looking for a solution that I can also do with vba script.

I believe not -
even with VB code referencing the specific ServiceID - you're still presented with both options. The only (albeit lame) recommendation is to give feedback in the question panel and hope someone bothers to review (as it's simply a hindrance otherwise)
Sub convert_to_dataType()
With ActiveCell
    .Value = "UniFonds"
     .ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:="en-GB"

End With
End Sub


However, I do believe you can define your own data types in ,power query - albeit have not explored the viability of that for this case.
